# Visual Studio Download prerequisistes from the following location gives error in compile time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

In my application I want to download prerequisite from the my server location. I am using Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

As seen in the above picture I am using "Download prerequisistes from the following location" option. But when I try to compile the project it gives the following error.

```
ERROR: To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SqlLocalDB2014SP1\sqllocaldb_x86.msi' for item 'SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express LocalDB' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.
```

But I am not using that option (option 2) but using the option 3. What might be the problem for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but my guess would be that you need to make sure the MSI indicated has to be put in the prerequisites folder. Did you try that?

Comment: Then what is the point of specifying the setup project to download it from the specified location?

Comment: Yes, putting the indicated msi files did fix the problem. I checked the install.log after installing using the .msi package and it has logged that the prerequisite has downloaded from the provided url. Seems like VS need it for like identify the prerequisite msi. Thanks anayway.